# Python generators and sum of multiples

Tags: python, generator

For the below question:
"Return the sum of the multiples of 3 and 5 below a number."

I tried to use:

```
def solution(number):
  return sum(x for x in range(1,number) if x%3==0 or x%5==0)
```

However this gives an overflow if the number is too large.  I'm not clear how as I tried to use a generator expression (I'm new to these). 
I thought it was evaluating each x in the range at a time (without building the list) and only keeping the running tally of sum and not building a list before  evaluating each item in the list. 
Can anyone explain why this doesn't work? Thanks.

Comment: _"However this gives an overflow if the number is too large"_. How large? Works fine on my machine all the way up to a hundred million.

Comment: Don't list comprehensions require brackets?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: as the OP says, this is a generator expression, not a list comprehension.

Comment: If you can do this on Python 3 you can take advantage of arbitrary int sizes. You're not overflowing your generator but the underlying C long type.

Comment: This doesn't run on Python 2. Aren't generators implicitly created in list comprehensions?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Yes it does, and no they aren't. Please ask your own question if you have a misunderstanding about generators. Commenting here is not appropriate.

Comment: Hmm tried on 50m on my machine and it's still going....

Comment: is this for project euler?

Comment: I tried 100 million and it worked for me.  Show your complete stacktrace.

Comment: "Still going" (taking a while to perform a loop with millions or billions of iterations) is not the same as `OverflowError`!

Comment: You should  also use xrange if you are use python2.

Comment: Ok I changed the xrange to range so it's python 3 compatible. Thanks for the responses.  Ok so the sum and the underlying long is the issue?  Is there a better way to do this as codewars didn't like my solution (gave an overflow error).  Stack trace? (I'm a bit of a newb)

Comment: what is the number you are solving for?

Comment: _"Stack trace? (I'm a bit of a newb)"_  When you received your "overflow error", python displayed many lines with important information.  Copy those lines here.

Comment: Ok yes it works at 500m for me - looks like codewars interpretor couldn't handle it for some reason.  Is this a good solution in the end or is there something better?

Comment: Hint: you can solve this problem just with pencil and paper. (and moderate knowledge of Triangular Numbers)

Comment: The error was "OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, that's not really an issue. An example with the `python3` linux shell:

```
>>> def solution(number):
...   return sum(x for x in range(10**15,number) if x%3==0 or x%5==0)
... 
>>> solution(10**15+20)
9000000000000082
>>> solution(10**15+17)
8000000000000065
```

(used `20**15` as offset to speed things up) don't seem to result in 32-bit integer overflows.

Since the sum of all `32`-bit integers can be represented by a `64`-bit integer and you want to sum up multiples up to a `32`-bit int, there is no problem with this.

It is possible one runs in memory overflow in `python2` simply because the list is generated before the sum actually takes place. and there is no way to represent billions of numbers in reasonable memory.

But the way this is handled is simply not the was to tackle this. The sum is simply equal to:

```
n//15-1
---
\                               15 (m+1) (7*m+8)
/     7*15*i+3+5+6+9+10+12+15 = ---------------- where m=n//15-1
---                                     2
i=0
```

and you need to take the last numbers into account as well.

So a method to calculate this is:

```
def sol15floor(n) :
    m = (n-1)//15-1
    s0 = 15*(m+1)*(7*m+8)//2
    return s0 + sum(x for x in range(15*m+16,n) if x%3==0 or x%5==0)
```

Comment: Thanks it's the codewars interpreter that gives that error and you are right not the standard python interpreter.  Sorry for the hassle.

Comment: @Yunti: as you can see the trick is not to perform brute force, but to use some smart trick (here a simple one, not optimal), so that mathematics save you most of the work.

Comment: Thanks I was focusing too much on the programming and completely forgetting to switch on my maths head.